# How to stop bot framework Skype channel removing numbers from numbered lists?

Tags: botframework, skype, skype-bots

I am trying to present a set of four choices that are each a sentence long. When I use choice prompts it renders it as a number list on the emulator and web chat. However, Skype stripes off the numbers. In all three cases, the user is expected to enter a number. However, in the case of Skype, they won't know what number goes with what. I redid it as a text prompt with a numbered list. Skype again stripped off the numbers. How do I work around this deviant behavior?

Does anyone know why Skype thinks this behavior is desirable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Skype is looking out for Bot Framework markdown numbered lists and removing the numbers.  So I changed from

1. option a,
2. option b

to

1 - option a

2 - option b

That's all it takes.